# Make Java Consumer accept Kotlin lambda

Tags: java, kotlin, groovy, functional-programming, dsl

This is likely an odd question, but I'm wondering if anyone has some thoughts on it.
I'm working on a DSL that we would like to be compatible with Java, Groovy, and Kotlin. I'm adding Kotlin compatibility to the current codebase, trying to duplicate as little as possible. It's worked well with the exception of one bit of code written in Groovy, using the Java Consumer functional interface:

```
PromptOptionals prompts(Consumer<PromptOptionals> definition) {
  DefaultPromptOptionals promptOptionals = new DefaultPromptOptionals()
  definition.accept(promptOptionals)
  prompts = promptOptionals.prompts
  promptOptionals
}
```

This prompts() method can be called from Java/Groovy fine, but when I call it with Kotlin:

```
prompts {
  say("test")
  pause(10)
  play("http://someserver.com/file")
}
```

The 3 method calls say, pause, and play are are add to the list promptOptionals.prompts, and everything goes as expected. But for Kotlin, when definition.accept(promptOptionals) is called, the methods are never added to the list, and the returned promptOptionals variable is just empty.
Is there any way that Consumer can be made compatible with Kotlin lambdas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course I'm not confident of your api but for me it looks strange that lambda's parameter is ignored. It might be you should write:

```kotlin
prompts { prompt ->
  prompt.say("test")
  prompt.pause(10)
  prompt.play("http://someserver.com/file")
}
```

Comment: You're right, that was it! Easier to resolve than I expected... although I am curious how painful it would be to fix up the syntax to not require the explicit parameter, as this is our Groovy equivalent:

`prompts {
  say 'test'
  pause 10
  play 'http://someserver.com/file'
}`

Comment: unfortunately, it's not possible for Java but quite easy for Kotlin. You can just use receiver argument in your lambda https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver. Sorry, I don't know will it still work for Groovy or not

Comment: @claxtastic In groovy this works due to the delegate in your code I assume? Above code should golf by using the impliciy `it`?